# Canny causes Assertion failed: _dx.type() == CV_16SC1 || _dx.type() == CV_16SC3 in function 'Canny'

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have been using android monscanner library in my react native app but as soon as i changed my library to opencv 4.5.4 it throws exception while getting corners. please help i am new to android and opencv. thanks

> modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:1057: error: (-215:Assertion failed) **_dx.type() == CV_16SC1 || _dx.type() == CV_16SC3 in function 'Canny'**

```
 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.1) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:1057: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _dx.type() == CV_16SC1 || _dx.type() == CV_16SC3 in function 'Canny'
    ]
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_0(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny(Imgproc.java:2216)
        at com.example.monscanner.ShapeValidationFragment.getPoints(ShapeValidationFragment.java:343)
        at com.example.monscanner.ShapeValidationFragment.shapeDetection(ShapeValidationFragment.java:301)
        at com.example.monscanner.ShapeValidationFragment.access$300(ShapeValidationFragment.java:68)
        at com.example.monscanner.ShapeValidationFragment$6.run(ShapeValidationFragment.java:183)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

android Code :

below is shapeDetection function

```
 private void shapeDetection(final Uri uri) {
        try {
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Bitmap originalBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), fileUri);
            scaledBmp = scanner.scaledBitmap(originalBmp, sourceframe.getWidth(), sourceframe.getHeight());
            Utils.bitmapToMat(scaledBmp,outerMat);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBmp, innerMat);

            srcGray = new Mat(outerMat.size(), CV_8UC1);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(outerMat, srcGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);

            rapport  = (float) (innerMat.size().height / outerMat.size().height);
            MatOfPoint points = getPoints();
            setPoints(points);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dismissDialog();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

and below is getPoints function to get MatOfPoint . it throws exception at imgproc.canny

```
 private MatOfPoint getPoints() {
        Mat blurred = new Mat();

        // valeur à modifier pour ajustements de la recherche de rectangles
        Imgproc.medianBlur(outerMat, blurred, 9);
        Mat threshOutput = new Mat(blurred.size(), CV_8UC1);
        squares = new ArrayList<>();
        List<MatOfPoint> threshSquares = new ArrayList<>();
        SparseArray<MatOfPoint> cannySquares = new SparseArray<>();
        indices = new ArrayList<>();


        // valeur à modifier pour ajustements de la recherche de rectangles

        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {

            int[] ch = {c, 0};
            MatOfInt cmat = new MatOfInt(ch);
            List<Mat> lblurred = new ArrayList<>();
            lblurred.add(blurred);
            List<Mat> loutput = new ArrayList<>();
            loutput.add(threshOutput);
            Core.mixChannels(lblurred,loutput,cmat);
//            Imgcodecs.imwrite(ScanConstants.IMAGE_PATH+"/"+c+".jpg",threshOutput);

            // tests de differents threshold
            int threshold_level = 3;
            for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++) {
                if (l == 0) {

                    for (int t=10; t<=60; t+=10) {

                        Imgproc.Canny(srcGray, srcGray, t, t*2,5,false);
                        Imgproc.dilate(srcGray, srcGray, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 2);
//                      Imgcodecs.imwrite(ScanConstants.IMAGE_PATH + "/" + c + "_" + l + "_" + t + ".jpg", srcGray);
                        findCannySquares(srcGray,cannySquares,c+t);
                    }
                } else {
                    // valeurs et calcul à modifier pour ajustements de la recherche de rectangles
                    Imgproc.threshold(threshOutput, srcGray, 200 - 175 / (l + 2f), 256, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
//                    Imgcodecs.imwrite(ScanConstants.IMAGE_PATH + "/" + c + "" + l + ".jpg", srcGray);

                    findThreshSquares(srcGray, threshSquares);
                }
            }
        }

        int indiceMax = maxi(indices);
        if (indiceMax != -1)
            squares.add(cannySquares.get(indiceMax));

        // Suppression des quadrilatères peu probables c'est à dire ceux qui touchent les bords
        List<MatOfPoint> squaresProba = new ArrayList<>();
        MatOfPoint pointsProba;
        List<Point> pointsList;
        int marge = (int) (srcGray.size().width*0.01f);
        boolean probable;
        for(int i=0;i<threshSquares.size();i++) {
            probable = true;
            pointsProba = threshSquares.get(i);
            pointsList = pointsProba.toList();
            for (Point p : pointsList) {
                if (p.x<marge || p.x>=srcGray.size().width-marge || p.y<marge || p.y>=srcGray.size().height-marge) {
                    probable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(probable) {
                squaresProba.add(pointsProba);
            }
        }

        // selection du quadrilatère le plus grand
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint();
        if (squaresProba.size()!=0) {
            double largest_area = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < squaresProba.size(); i++) {
                double a = Imgproc.contourArea(squaresProba.get(i), false);
                if (a > largest_area && a < srcGray.size().height * srcGray.size().width) {
                    largest_area = a;
                    largest_contour_index = i;
                }
            }

            if (squaresProba.size() > 0) {
                points = squaresProba.get(largest_contour_index);
            } else {
                List<Point> pts = new ArrayList<>();
                pts.add(new Point(0, 0));
                pts.add(new Point(outerMat.size().width, 0));
                pts.add(new Point(0, outerMat.size().height));
                pts.add(new Point(outerMat.size().width, outerMat.size().height));
                points.fromList(pts);
            }
        }
        else {
            double largest_area = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < threshSquares.size(); i++) {
                double a = Imgproc.contourArea(threshSquares.get(i), false);
                if (a > largest_area && a < srcGray.size().height * srcGray.size().width) {
                    largest_area = a;
                    largest_contour_index = i;
                }
            }

            if (threshSquares.size() > 0) {
                points = threshSquares.get(largest_contour_index);
            } else {
                List<Point> pts = new ArrayList<>();
                pts.add(new Point(0, 0));
                pts.add(new Point(outerMat.size().width, 0));
                pts.add(new Point(0, outerMat.size().height));
                pts.add(new Point(outerMat.size().width, outerMat.size().height));
                points.fromList(pts);
            }
        }
        squares.add(points);

        // Ajout des autres contours après les 2 plus importants
        for (int id : indices) {
            if (id!=indiceMax)
                squares.add(cannySquares.get(id));
        }
        for (int id=0; id<threshSquares.size(); id++) {
            if (id!=largest_contour_index) {
                squares.add(threshSquares.get(id));
            }
        }

        return squares.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: I highlighted the assertion that was violated. ponder its meaning. your data has the wrong type. check what type your data has.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it is working  with openCVLibrary341. so now I am using it.